# Khovanov $A_\infty$ algebra

Tags: co.combinatorics, homotopy-theory, knot-theory, a-infinity-algebras, khovanov-homology

Let $L$ be a link in $\mathbb{R}^3$, with $D, D'$ be diagrams in
$\mathbb{R}^2$ representing $L$. Khovanov constructed two graded
chain complexes $$C_{D} = (Ch_{D}, d_{D}) \quad C_{D'}=(Ch_{D'},
d_{D'})$$ and proved that their homologies $Kh(D), Kh(D')$ are
isomorphic. This defines an invariant for the link $L$, namely
the Khovanov homology $Kh(L)$.

Mantra in algebraic topology suggests that we should not be
taking homology too quickly (to avoid forgetting useful
information).

I thus wonder if there are some weaker equivalences between
$C_{D}$ and $C_{D'}$. Indeed there is: the Khovanov homology is
known to be a degeneration of Khovanov homotopy type (i.e. a
refined invariant $\tilde{Kh}(L))$ which is a homotopy type up to
homotopy equivalence). How about a version in terms of
equivalence of $A_\infty$ algebras? If such Khovanov $A_\infty$
algebra indeed exists, is it stricly weaker than the Khovanov
homotopy type?

Comment: I think this is very speculative because apparently you don’t even know whether such an A-infinity algebra structure exists.

Comment: Khovanov homology is not a ring. If you know a ring structure, write a paper and wow a lot of people. The refinement is to a *stable* homotopy type (finite CW-spectrum), and spectra do not have cohomology rings: stabilization destroys the cup product. (You should write a proof of that as an exercise if you don't already know it.) What you do get is an action of the Steenrod algebra on Khovanov homology and people certainly do investigate this at the chain level, eg arXiv:1204.5776